# Enumerate all tags in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

How do I generate an enumerated list of all tags (e.g., `:tag:`) in an org-mode file? Say I have a list of the form:

```
* Head1        :foo:bar:
** Subhead1    :foo:
* Head2
** Subhead2    :foo:bar:
```

I want to generate a list of all tags in this file as well as how many times each tag was used. Say something like,

```
:foo:    3
:bar:    2
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a shorter version.

```
(defun get-tag-counts ()
  (let ((all-tags '()))
    (org-map-entries
     (lambda ()
       (let ((tag-string (car (last (org-heading-components)))))
     (when tag-string   
       (setq all-tags
         (append all-tags (split-string tag-string ":" t)))))))


    ;; now get counts
    (loop for tag in (-uniq all-tags) 
      collect (cons tag (cl-count tag all-tags :test 'string=)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not make use of the [code posted by John Kitchin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330980/enumerate-all-tags-in-org-mode#27527252), as it requires an interactive function. *bpalmer* from *IRC freenode/#emacs* was so kind to help me out. Please find a working example that spits out all tags below the respective tree.

```lisp
; use this in order to be able to use loop on its own
(require 'cl)
 
;; count tags (see John's answer)
(defun get-tag-counts ()
  (let ((all-tags '()))
    (org-map-entries
     (lambda ()
       (let ((tag-string (car (last (org-heading-components)))))
         (when tag-string  
           (setq all-tags
                 (append all-tags (split-string tag-string ":" t)))))))
 
    ;; now get counts
    (loop for tag in (seq-uniq all-tags)
          collect (cons tag (cl-count tag all-tags :test 'string=)))))

;; wrap get-tag-counts in an interactive function
(defun create-tag-counts-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((tags (get-tag-counts)) (b (get-buffer-create "*Org Tag Count*")))
    (dolist (tag tags) (insert (car tag)) (insert "\n")) (display-buffer b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach.

```
(setq my-hash (make-hash-table :test 'equal))

(org-map-entries
 (lambda ()
   (let ((tag-string (car (last (org-heading-components))))
     (current-count))
     (when tag-string   
       (dolist (tag (split-string tag-string ":" t))

      (setq current-count (gethash tag my-hash))
     (if current-count;
         (puthash tag (+ 1 current-count)  my-hash)
       (puthash tag 1 my-hash))
     )
       )
     )
   )
 )

;; https://github.com/Wilfred/ht.el
(require 'ht)
(ht-map
 (lambda (key value)
   (list key value))
  my-hash)
```